# That would require that he imagine(s?) something

Tags: grammar, tense, present-tense, third-person-singular

Which one is correct? And why?

1. "That would require that he imagine something."
2. "That would require that he imagine**s** something."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be.

The former suggests that whatever-it-is would demand that he imagine something then and there. The latter suggests that there be a requirement that he already imagines something.

This is because the sentence structural position of "that he imagine(s) something" can take phrases of different nature, and a requirement can be to do something, or for some condition to be met. The first example is a required action, while the second is a required condition.

Even for the action, you would usually say "he imagines" - that's how it conjugates in the third person singular, after all. But when an action is stated to be required things work differently. I *think*, but I'm not sure, is that it uses the infinite, and sometimes infinitives can be bare - as they are when there is a requirement using "that". "I require you to be silent" is using a non-bare infinitive, while "I require that you be silent" uses the bare infinitive.

Comment: Answer updated :)

Comment: Is this not simply an example of the distinction between the use of the subjunctive **If I were in your position** and the popular **If I was in your position....**?